# MySQL Select box Duplicate - Duplicating one field option but not the other (Queries Identical)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently creating a database for an upload system - I am using a select box to limit the number of categories added to the database.

```
<select name="category">
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "blah", "blah") or die ("No connection");

mysqli_select_db($conn, "UPLOAD") or die("db will not open");

$query = "SELECT category FROM details GROUP BY category";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value=\"" . $row[0] . "\">" . $row[0] . "</option>";
                }               
             mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
     </select>

    <select name="reaction">
            <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "blah", "blah") or die ("No connection");

            mysqli_select_db($conn, "UPLOAD") or die("db will not open");

            $query = "SELECT reaction FROM details GROUP BY reaction";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value=\"" . $row[0] . "\">" . $row[0] . "</option>";
                }               
             mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
```

While the two queries are the same - Only the Category (The top query) is stopping form repeating multiple data from my db. When I look into my database - This is what I am finding (Which I have a hunch may be the problem).

```
INSERT INTO `details` (`name`, `category`, `reaction`, `photo`, `date_added`) VALUES
('Mase Laughing', 'Funny', 'Laugh\n', 'mase-laugh.gif', '2013-05-01 07:16:26'),
('Movie Wink', 'Cheeky', 'Wink\n', 'movie-wink.gif', '2013-05-02 12:33:12'),
('Tarzan Giggle', 'Funny', 'Wink\r\n', 'tarzan-laugh.gif', '2013-05-02 01:33:00');
```

Beside the reactions I am getting these strange `\r\n` letters - 
Anyone have any Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you're establishing and disconnecting DB connection multiple times?

Comment: I am Kind of new to all this

Comment: You want to add multiple reaction but it fails? Like the selext box has 'funny', 'shocked', 'boo' reactions. And I can select boo and funny and those two reaction will be stored on the database?

Comment: It all works fine - Its only that the select boxes get populated with multiple results of say Wink or Laugh. Kind of like Laugh-Wink-Wink instead of just Laugh and Wink.

Comment: When I REMOVED both `Wink` values (completely) from `reaction` field and then executed query it shows me two values (laugh,Wink) in Select box. Problem might be because of `Wink\n` and `Wink\r\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are "Carriage Return" (\r) and "Newline" (\n) characters. These are commands telling your computer to go the end of the line and to a new line.

To stop your page from showing duplicate categories, change this:

```
$query = "SELECT category FROM details GROUP BY category";
```

into this:

```
$query = "SELECT distinct category FROM details GROUP BY category";
```

It will not prevent your database from storing duplicate categories (which you do no want, otherwise you would only be able to save 1 (one) line of details per categorie, but it will prevent your dropdown (select) from showing the duplicates. So, with the details you showed, it will give you a dropdown with the values 'Funny' and 'Cheecky', both of them showing only once.
Add "distinct" to your other SQL statement too to have the reactions de-duplicated too:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT reaction FROM details GROUP BY reaction";
```

Comment: Ah - nothing to be alarmed about then?

Comment: Not at all my friend :-) It just means they pressed "enter". And depending on their system (windows/linux/mac/...), that enter is translated in \n or \r\n.

Comment: Ah- Thanks That makes sence

Comment: It's not fixed yet tho - My select box for reaction is still duplicating options :(

Comment: Thats the code I input buddy it could be something to do with how its being uploaded

Comment: Because wink\n and Wink\n\r are two different values to your database. Remove these, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am updating original question by reducing redundant code

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("No connection");
    mysqli_select_db($conn, "test") or die("db will not open");
?>
<select name="category">
<?php

    $query = "SELECT category FROM details GROUP BY category";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[0] . "</option>";
    }               
?>
</select>

<select name="reaction">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT reaction FROM details GROUP BY reaction";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[0] . "</option>";
    }               
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Even you could do one thing that whenever you allow entry in text fields replace combination of `\r\n` to `\n` so that no mismatched will be occured.